# How to format Javascript Fetch API output

Tags: javascript, json, rest, fetch

The REST API that I'm using returns data in the following format:

```
data:1
data:2
data:3
```

I would like to display the output in the following format instead:

```
123
```

This is how I'm making an API call using Javascript Fetch (with test url as an example):

```
let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" // test url
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      let htmlOutput = document.getElementById("htmlOutput");
      // parsing the JSON value to string
      htmlOutput.value = JSON.stringify(data);
    })
```

How can I format the output that I get when I make a call to an API, the way I want?

Answer (score 1):

```
htmlOutput.value = data.map(e => e.data).join('');
```

```js
const data = [{ data: 1 }, { data: 2 }, { data: 3 }]
const result = data.map(e => e.data).join('');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Updated the answer + included a snippet, does that work?